# How can i build a node.js file to be hosted on netlify?

Tags: node.js, netlify

This is the code i use for test

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
const PORT = 5000;
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    // Get the requested file's path
    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if (filePath === './') {
        filePath = './homepage.html'; // Default to homepage.html
    }
    // Determine the content type based on file extension
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    switch (extname) {
        case '.html':
            contentType = 'text/html';
            break;
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
        case '.mjs':
            contentType = 'module';
            break;
    }
    fs.readFile(filePath, function (error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if (error.code == 'ENOENT') {
                response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                response.end('<h1>404 Not Found</h1>');
            } else {
                response.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                response.end('<h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>');
            }
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
}).listen(PORT);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:' + PORT);
```

What do i have to change to deploy on netlify? and what build command should i use?

I tried
`node server.js`
the file name is server.js, but it doesn't work. I think that is beacuse something with the port.